# Angular 2 RC5 Router redirect with Auth0 service

Tags: angular, oauth, routes, angular2-routing, auth0

I have a simple application using Angular 2. I am currently on the RC5 using the NgModule. I am using the 3.0.0-beta.2 Router.

My default app URL is currently

> http://localhost:8080/#

When I login using the Auth0 service, after a successful login the get the access_token and id_token in the url. The redirecting url looks like this

> http://localhost:8080/#access_token=YKXQzxxx&id_token=eyjQWASxxx

But now the Angular Router tries to map this as a route. So I get the below error.

**

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'access_token'

**

Is there a way I can tell Angular not to do this. I want to read the data back as a router param instead. Please help.

Comment: Can't you influence the redirect URL of Auth0? If you can, just create a route where you read the params and then redirect to another route using `this.router.navigate(...)`. If this isn't possible try to add a route with path `'**'` (catch-all)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: Same issue here but with 2.0.0. Did you solve it?